# error during VS Debugging but no error when run exe file directly

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I have a very simple c++ sample project that basically just logs in to a 3rd party library (collection of .lib files)

There are 4 provided configurations md,mdd,mt,mtd. All x64.

I can build in mdd mode and run the Exe file directly, and the program works fine.

But if I run the debugger in VS, the 3rd party library throws a runtime Exception "vector deleting destructor".

```
 try
 {
    engine = new Engine(&params);   
 }
    catch (XxxException& Ex)
 {
    return (ERROR);
 }


Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA52003FB8 in Sample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: XxxException at memory location 0x000000224C53F190.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA52003FB8 in Sample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: XxxException at memory location 0x000000224C53F690.

0x00007ff75d5ab3e0 {Sample.exe!const XxxException::`vftable'} {0x00007ff75d2d8a50 {Sample.exe!XxxException::`vector deleting destructor'(unsigned int)}}
```

So I am unable to debug.

What is this error, and why does it only occur in VS Debugger?

Comment: That cannot be the full text of the exception message

Comment: Contact the author of the 3rd party library for support with their product.

Comment: I cant step through. it throws from the 3rd party library! nothing to step in to. no debugging symbols on the provided .lib files.

Comment: Depending on how visual studio is configured, the debugger will also stop on exceptions that don't cause a problem, because they are inside a try catch block. In this case, when the debugger had stopped, you can just continue execution to ignore the exception

Comment: thanks i added more detail. i tried skipping the exceptions but the library does not initialise properly because of this debug error.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change the working directory as specified in Debugging from $(ProjectDir)

to $(TargetPath), where the exe was sitting!

isn't C++ a wonderful artifact of history!